# Creating an instance of a class in wx Python like normal OOP classes

Tags: python-2.7, inheritance, wxpython, instantiation

I am trying to learn OOP and wx Python concurrently, and I am finding creating an instance of a class when using wx difficult. I don't know what I am missing, but see the code below and you can see my confusion with the last line before the loop. In a normal inheritance scenario, I could create an instance of the class DailyTasks and then call a method using that instance. Why not in wx? Is it because I am not using the object class in the parent class and instead have to use wx.Frame and wx.Panel? I hope this makes sense what I am asking. The first part of the code is the behavior that I would expect without wx, and the second group of code is the wx code that is confusing me. Thanks in advance for your help.

```
----------

class Animals(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def eat(self, food):
        print '%s eats the %s'% (self.name, food)

    def breath(self):
        print '%s breaths through lungs'%(self.name)

class Dog(Animals):
    def gets_mad(self):
        print 'When %s gets mad, %s bites'%(self.name, self.name)

    def show_affection(self):
        print '%s shows affection and wags his tail'% (self.name)

    def fetch(self,thing):
        print '%s chases and brings back the %s'% (self.name, thing)

class Cat(Animals):
    def gets_mad(self):
        print 'When %s gets mad, %s will scratch you'%(self.name, self.name)

    def show_affection(self):
        print '%s shows affection and purrs'% (self.name)

    def fetch(self):
        print "%s doesn't fetch anything" % (self.name)

r = Dog('Rover')  #instantiating to Dog class 
c = Cat('Fluffy')
c.show_affection()
r.show_affection()
c.fetch()
r.fetch('ball')
r.eat('dogfood')
c.eat('catfood')
c.gets_mad()
r.gets_mad()
rex = Dog('Ralph')
rex.eat('steak')


----------


import wx

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title='My File Organization')
        book = wx.Notebook(self)
        page = Settings(parent=book)
        page2 = DailyTasks(parent=book)
        book.AddPage(page, 'Settings')
        book.AddPage(page2,'Daily Tasks')
        self.SetSize(wx.Size(1024,768))
        self.Centre()

class Settings(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self, pos = (0,0),
        size=(1024,768))
        self.file_text = wx.StaticText(self.panel,
        -1, "Daily Tasks Button 1 Path", (40,20))
        self.file_text_box = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel,
        -1,pos = (170,15), size = (240,20), style = 0, value = 'C:\Documents')
        self.file_button_text = wx.StaticText(self.panel,
        -1, "Button Name", (420,20))
        self.file_button_text_box = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel,
        -1,pos = (500,15), size = (140,20), style = 0, value = 'Zombies')
        self.file_text2 = wx.StaticText(self.panel, -1,
        "Daily Tasks Button 2 Path", (40,50))
        self.file_text_box2 = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel,
        -1,pos = (170,45), size = (240,20), style = 0, value = 'C:\\')
        self.file_button_text2 = wx.StaticText(self.panel,
        -1, "Button Name", (420,50))
        self.file_button_text_box2 = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel,
        -1,pos = (500,45), size = (140,20), style = 0, value = 'Angels')

class DailyTasks(Settings):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = None
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self, pos = (0,0), size=(1024,768))

    def test(self):
        print 'testing'

dt = DailyTasks()  # This is where I have the question and need to create
                   # an instance of the DailyTasks class.

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    MyFrame().Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0):

wx should allow inheritance in the normal manner. Can you expand on what the actual behavior is when you assign dt to your instance of DailyTask()

Comment: That is the problem. when I try to instantiate with dt, it says that it takes 2 arguments probably because of the parent input in DailyTasks __init__. Whatever I try to put in the parentheses either is not defined or expects a wx.window requirement. I have tried to remove parent, but that causes issues with the GUI as well.

Comment: Wait have you tried sending a window or window child as the parent. Self is the first implied param but you will need to populate the second...